# Matplotlib complains about not finding Qt platform plugin "wayland"

Tags: python, qt, 21.04, anaconda, matplotlib

I have trouble getting Matplotlib to work on Ubuntu 21.04. Whenever I want to plot something I'm getting the following error message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

fish: “python3” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

This is a short minimal reproducible example:

```
❯ python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
```

I'm using Anaconda/Mamba and Python 3.9.5. I've made sure to reinstall all Matplotlib dependencies, but it still complains.

I've Google searched for 20min to no avail. This particular error doesn't seem to have been reported on Stackoverflow or similar.

Comment: Have you tried switching to Xorg session on login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue in Pycharm.

Installing opencv-python-headless solved it.

Although it does then interfere with standard opencv...

I deployed in a container so not an issue for me, but be aware.